# Integer in html output (jupyter notebook)

Tags: python, html, jupyter

Is it possible to combine python output with html? I want to include the integer i in the note string (like the blue number)
[image: Jupyter notebook]

Comment: kindly post the code here instead of an image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest way to do it is construct the string:

```py
htmlOutput = '<h2>Note: '+ str(i) +'</h2>'
```

and inject the string in your snippet:

```py
from IPython.core.display import display, HTML

for i in range(10):
  htmlOutput = '<h2>Note: '+ str(i) +'</h2>'
  display(HTML(htmlOutput))
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work for you :

```
from IPython.core.display import display,HTML
for i in range(10):
    display(HTML('<h2>Note %s</h2> '%i))
```

The output willl be:

```
Note 0
Note 1
Note 2
Note 3
Note 4
Note 5
Note 6
Note 7
Note 8
Note 9
```